# How to get a asp:Panel's CSS Class in code-behind after it has changed by CSS

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css

I have a Panel control who's class is changed via javascript. When the user click a button, I need to check the Panel's CSS class and if it is the changed value, then I need to do stuff. The problem is, once I change the CSS class using Javascript, the server is not getting that information back. I need the server to recognize that the class has changed. I have attempted `__doPostback` but that messes up many of the elements on the page. Looking for suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could add a `hidden control` to your page and store it there..

I.E in ASPX

```
 <asp:HiddenField runat="server" id="hdnCSS" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

When you run your JS add a little code to populate this hidden field.

```
$("#hdnCSS").val("yourValue"); // jquery

 OR

document.getElementById("hdnCSS").value = "yourValue" // javascript
```

When you postback, the value will be available in `hdnCSS.Value`